# Dual boot W10/Linux on Acer Aspire V15 Nitro

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint, arch-linux

I have a 
[Acer Aspire V15 Nitro black edition](http://www.fnac.com/mp28794200/Acer-Aspire-V-15-Nitro-7-592G-57NQ-Black-Edition-15-6-Core-i5-6300HQ-8-Go-RAM-1-To-HDD/w-4?adhce=crtdcvrt2014&ectrans=1&gclid=Cj0KEQiA3Y7GBRD29f-7kYuO1-ABEiQAodAvwLNUa9s2mYrg3cac6OULYAqLDS82w4ytIbp6tljlCl4aAnAl8P8HAQ&oref=408a16d8-0040-ee40-1fdd-83ad90235b2c&Origin=CMP_GOOGLE_MP_MICRO%2C&pcrid=98297423423&plid=&ploc=9056242&ptid=pla-87971146370) and I've been wanting to have it in dual boot with some kind of Linux distribution for a while (I'd like to program on it rather than windows) tho i've tried a lot of things and it never worked... I've looked at a lot of posts on stack exchange, and on forums around the internet and none worked...

So I've been running Linux on Virtual Box from Oracle ™ but I'm getting bored, it's slow so i'd like to try again

Can somebody give me steps to follow, so I can try them out and give you the error/problems I get ?

Thanks a lot :)

PS : I'd love to use archlinux for example because it's configurable :D

Answer (score 0):

try using other virutal machine such as VMWARE it reqire 64-bit operating and it work good

Comment: Thanks I've tried it but it's not the kind of answer I'm looking for :/